# Ajax Post returning 500 error ie8 and ie9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, post, xdomainrequest

I have gone through every stackoverflow post about this but still can't figure out why its not working.

I have a simple jquery ajax post that works everywhere except ie8 and ie9.

The server is asp.Net

Index.html has:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Jquery Post:

```
$.ajax({ 
        // cache: false,
        // crossDomain: true,
        // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        type: "POST",
        url: self.dom.API+"/api/xxx/InsertUser",
        dataType: "json",
        data: postData,
        success: function(data){     
            if(data.Status == "Success"){
                self.onSubmitSuccess();
            }
            else{
                self.unknownError();
            }
        },
        error: function(data){

        }
    });
```

I also added this plugin to fight the Xdomin security issue. 
https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/xdr.js

Error & Response via Charles

```
Response: {"Message":"An error has occurred."}

POST /api/xxx/InsertUser HTTP/1.1
Accept  */*
Origin  http://local.xxx.com
Accept-Language en-US
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
Host    xxx-api.xxx.com
Content-Length  206
Pragma  no-cache

URL http://xxx-api.xxx.com/api/xxx/InsertUser
Status  Complete
Response Code   500 Internal Server Error
Protocol    HTTP/1.1
Method  POST
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Client Address  /127.0.0.1
Remote Address  xxx.com/ipaddress
```

Comment: are you using asp.net ?

Comment: yes. A buddy of mine did the backend

Comment: Try `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>`

Comment: Can you run the same code *on* the web server so that you can see what the 500 error actually is?  It'll point you to the problem in the server code.

Comment: Please note this is a POST and not a GET. Just updated, sorry.

Comment: @Archer, do you mean through charles or just typing in a serialized url?  Nice username btw

Comment: @TusharGupta no luck on the content="IE=9". Thanks

Comment: Error 500 is 100% server-side problem OR from IE you sending something different than in other browsers. Could you please provide Request headers?